# Where and how to store text files for reading/writing

Tags: java, jar, text-files, persistent-storage

I have an app that accesses words from a `csv` text files. Since they usually do not change I have them placed inside a `.jar` file and read them using `.getResourceAsStream` call. I really like this approach since I do not have to place a bunch of files onto a user's computer - I just have one `.jar` file.

The problem is that I wanted to allow "admin" to add or delete the words within the application and then send the new version of the app to other users. This would happen very rarely (99.9% only read operations and 0.1% write). However, I found out that it is not possible to write to text files inside the `.jar` file. Is there any solution that would be appropriate for what I want and if so please explain it in detail as I'm still new to Java.

Comment: Read a file that is stored external to the jar? This way the user/admin is able to edit the file by himself.

Comment: It sounds like there needs to be a service to centralize the management of the list of words.

Comment: Do you mean like an online database of words?

Comment: Is this WEB application or a desktop app? How fast do you want the changes to be visible? How do you deploy this app currently?

Comment: It is a desktop app, the speed of changes is not really the key for me (unless it will take hours which I doubt) and I'm not quite sure what you ask for with "how do I deploy it" but I export the app into a runnable jar file. The best would be if it worked offline but I guess that in the modern days of Internet I can live with online solution as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible because You can't change any content of a jar which is currently used by a JVM.
Better Choose alternate solution like keeping your jar file and text file within the same folder

Comment: But that way all the users would see the csv file and be able to directly edit it via text editor. Plus I would have to copy all the files whenever I would want to send the app to someone else right?

Comment: You can add Database instead of file to prevent from other or use some encryption algorithm in file

Comment: Hmh could you point me to the right direction with the database? Write more about this solution or post some other question where they discuss it?

Comment: if you are creating a standalone application runs on single machine go with a static database like MySQL or else use file outside a jar and encrypt all the data with any one of an encryption algorithm which will allow you to hide the data from the user